# Site-to-site VPN tunnel limits in Azure

Tags: azure

How many Site to Site VPN tunnels can be created per virtual network in Azure? I know that Point to Site can handle 128 supported connections but trying to find out how many for site to site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer:
There are 3 tiers to VPN Gateways in Azure now.
Basic supports 10 
Standard supports 10 
High Performance supports 30

Here is the link to the documentation:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-about-vpngateways/